# how to update database using datagridview?

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

how do we update tables using datagridview? assuming the datagridview is editable at runtime?  any kind of help is appreciated.

```
 Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:\record.accdb"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM StudentRecords"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")
        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Database is now Closed")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "AddressBook"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps:

1. Iterate the Rows collection of DataGridView using For Each or simple For loop
2. Write UPDATE statement to save changes.